# How to achieve image collage view with intelligent scaling without cropping, as in Google Keep

Tags: android

I pretty like the image collage view as in Google Keep.

[image]

I try the following library

https://github.com/lopei/collageview

```
    CollageView collageView = (CollageView) findViewById(R.id.collageView);

    collageView
        .photoMargin(1)
        .photoPadding(3)
        .backgroundColor(Color.RED)
        .photoFrameColor(Color.BLUE)
        .useFirstAsHeader(false)
        .defaultPhotosForLine(3)
        .useCards(true)
        .loadPhotos(new int[] {R.drawable.one, R.drawable.three, R.drawable.two, R.drawable.zero});
```

The best I can achieve is

[image]

If you pay attention carefully. There's one significant different. In Google Keep, it is able to scale the image more intelligently, so that there's no image cropping. All image information can be seen from the thumbnail. No information is lost.

I was wondering, do you have any idea, how can I achieve the same effect as in Google Keep?

Comment: just want to say that I'm a brother of the `CollageView` lib developer. We'll try to improve it

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Than you, and looking forward the lib improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I had read the code of `collageview` and tried out.

I think the key of the solution is to apply correct `layout_weight` on the `ImageView`.

Take the following example

```
Image0 = 1280 x 720
Image1 = 685 x 963
Image2 = 1280 x 856

layout_weight for image 0 = 1 (since its height is the lowest)

layout_weight for image 1 = height0/height1 * width1/width0
                          = 720/963 * 685/1280 = 0.4001168224

layout_weight for image 2 = height0/height2 * width2/width0
                          = 720/856 * 1280/1280 = 0.8411214953
```

So, using the following XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/three"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4001168224"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/two"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8411214953"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/one"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It looks like this

[image]

This is how it looks like, without applying `layout_weight`.
[image]